# How to use p:ajax oncomplete event on p:fileUpload. Getting error when using

Tags: primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 2.2. I am using p:fileuplaod, when fileUploads then using update i change the image on  my page. Here it is.

```
<p:fileUpload id="countryFlag" widgetVar="uploader" description="Image"
      update="Flag" allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;" auto="true"
      fileUploadListener="#{countryPages_Detail.imageUpload}">

    <p:ajax oncomplete="test('Flag')" />

</p:fileUpload>

<p:graphicImage id="Flag" value="#{countryPages_Detail.imagePath}"
      width="80" height="50" cache="false">

    <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{countryPages_Detail.putImage}" />                                                 

</p:graphicImage>
```

What i want to do using script is that when upload completes, and using ajax when the image has been changed, then i want to check the image src attribute. Here is my test() function, it is not complete, but here it is

```
function test(imageId) {

    var imgId = imageId;
    var image =  $("#saarcImagesTable tr").find("img[id='imageId']")
    alert("Image change");
}
```

But I am getting error that

> Parent not an instance of ClientBehaviorHolder: org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload@e39f71

Why am I am getting this error? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p:fileUpload` component does not implement the ClientBehaviorHolder interface as the message states and therefore is no component that can contain the ajax tag (see [this post](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16260)).

I am not familiar with the fileUpload component, but I've seen in the documentation of PF 3.2 that the `p:fileUpload` has an `oncomplete` attribute.

Comment: Hmm the link that you posted has a comment that `fileuploads and ajax are a different story. Use advanced mode if you want ajax uploads.`What is advanced mode? Can you tell me any other way through which i can detect change event in the p:graphicImage? Like whenever p:graphicImage changes then my javascript function get call. Actually i have a h:datagrid in which there are 4 columns. `name, fileuplload, graphicImage, removeLink`. By default p:graphicImage has a default image. I want to check if p:graphicImages changes then somehow i come to know. Someone gave me suggestion of using oncomplete.

Comment: The advanced mode is for PF 3.x version. The opposite simple mode is the legacy mode to behave like 2.x file uploader. So all you need is in the newer PF ;-(. But you have a server side action method (the upload listener) and your p:graphicImage has a bean bound value attribute. Can't you check that on the server side?

Comment: Actually what i want to do is that whenever my p:graphicImage changes then i have to check whether p:graphicImage contains the default image or any other image. If it has default image then i have to hide the remove link otherwise it is showing. Here you can find that what i want with the code that i posted[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125231/how-to-hide-element-in-responce-of-ajax-call#comment12979201_10125231. Here i am using server side code. No matter it is client or server side i just want that when my p:graphicImage changes then i can take the appropriate action. Thanks