# How to hide a button until an action is completed? Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

i currently have a file upload system in place, and currently i have a button to take the user to the next page, but this is visible even if the user has not uploaded anything, the danger is here if the user presses this before uploading anything it will throw an error and look bad, so what i am trying to do is hide this button until file upload is successfully achieved, any ideas how ?

```
<p:fileUpload widgetVar="upload" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
                                  mode="advanced" 
                                  multiple="false" 
                                  update="messages"
                                  label="Select File"
                                  sizeLimit="100000000" 
                                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|doc|docx|txt|pdf|html)$/"
                                  auto="true"/> 
                    <!-- selected auto="true" this has been selected to prevent user error as was discovered 
                    when testing, some users pressed the upload button and wondered why nothing worked instead of
                    select file, now this stops this -->


                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

                    Please press the button below once you have uploaded the file, to continue


                    <p:commandButton action="#{navigationBean.naviagtion}"   value="Next"  ajax="False"/>
```

the command button of action next is the one i wish to disable untill file upload is complete

EDIT :

```
<p:commandButton action="#{navigationBean.naviagtion}"   value="Next"  ajax="False" disabled="#{!fileUploadController.UploadComplete}"/>
```

Is my command button, it is pointing to the fileUploadContoller, this is where the file upload happens etc,

the issue is when i run the app i get a live button always on page load

i have added a boolean onto my fileUploadController :

```
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        //System.out.println("DesintationPDF : " + destinationPDF);
        System.out.println("called handle file");
        System.out.println("Destination is : " + configProp.getProperty("destination"));

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded."); //Displays to user on the webpage
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);


        try {
            copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
//handle the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public boolean isUploadComplete() {
        return uploadComplete;
    }

    public void setUploadComplete(boolean uploadComplete) {
        this.uploadComplete = uploadComplete;
    }
```

but still get the error

EDIT 2 :

```
     <p:commandButton action="#{navigationBean.naviagtion}"   value="Next" disabled="#{!fileUploadController.uploadComplete}"/>
```

the console

```
INFO: Upload complete value before copy file false
INFO: upload complete value is : true
```

so it is changing the value to true

but is not changing the button to live

Comment: what about disabling the button and enable it, when the upload has finished? seems much more intuitive to me than suddenly rendering it. also I suggest you to use PrimeFaces, since it's awesome. (but that's just an additional thing)

Comment: that would be a perfect solution, i am currently using primefaces to create the fileupload and the button is also primefaces, how would i go about disabling and re enabling it ? will post code of my current set up

Comment: `#{navigationBean.naviagtion}"` there's probably a typo in there.

Comment: `#{navigationBean.naviagtion}"` points to a java bean i have that takes the user to another page, this is currently working perfectly

Comment: the property is named `naviagtion`? not `navigation`?

Comment: Yea a typo when i created the property !,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable your button until the upload finished, just bind the `disabled` attribute to a property in a bean. In my opinion disabling seems much more intuitive than suddenly rendering it. Also the user will know that there's something going on in the background.

```
 <p:commandButton action="#{navigationBean.naviagtion}" value="Next" disabled="#{bean.disable}" ajax="False"/>
```

Since you use PrimeFaces, this solution is the easiest. Just replace `bean` with the name of your bean.

Edit:

```
public class YourNavigationBean {

    private boolean uploadComplete; // <--- that's the property

    // ... your bean content, like constructors and stuff..
    // ...

    //a setter and a getter is needed, to here they are
    public boolean isUploadComplete() {
       return uploadComplete;
    }
    public void setUploadComplete(boolean uploadComplete) {
       this.uploadComplete = uploadComplete;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how do i bind the disable attribute to the bean that is completing the file upload ?

Comment: Just add another `boolean` property in your `navigationBean`, e.g. name it `uploadComplete`. Set it to `true`, when the upload completes. In your button it then would be: `disabled="#{!navigationBean.uploadComplete}"`

Comment: Sorry i am new to this, what do you mean add another boolean property, do you have an example ?

Comment: Thanks, i have tried that an am now getting an error, have edited the original question to show my code and the error, what have i done wrong ?

Comment: of course the property must be named `isUploadComplete()` not `isComplete()`. My bad.

Comment: Thanks i have just done that, no errors but now the button is no disabled, whenever i go to the page the button is always enabled

Comment: well, I should write my code all myself... look at the setter, there was a `this` missing, so the attribute was never changed ;)

Comment: Thanks i have added the this. but it is still always live on page load

Comment: @user2065929 I'm also quite new to jsf, but I found that you also need to update your button. Maybe you should read and google a bit update `<p:ajax`, events and `fileupload`. for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135689/how-to-use-pajax-oncomplete-event-on-pfileupload-getting-error-when-using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923937/pcommandbutton-doing-the-opposite-of-what-i-require

Comment: already found it, had some research. answering at the moment, be prepared ;)

Answer (score 1):

make the next button as invisible. maintain a flag = false in the beginning, after successfully uploading the file make the flag as true. or at the end of the file upload make next button visible to true;

Comment: Thanks, how would i go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

ON upload complete event set display=block.

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="submit" style="display:none" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                   document.getElementById("submitbutton").style.display='block'; 
                } 
            }
            );
    });
```

Live demo:http://jsfiddle.net/E42XA/205/