# p:commandbutton doing the opposite of what i require

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have been trying to have a disabled button until and action is complete and then this should enable the button

The code for the button :

```
<p:commandButton action="#{navigationBean.naviagtion}"   value="Next" disabled="#{!fileUploadController.uploadComplete}"/>
```

This is the bean FileUploadController it is a managed and view scoped bean

```
    private boolean uploadComplete;

            uploadComplete = false;
            System.out.println("Upload complete value before copy file " + uploadComplete);
            copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());


        } catch (IOException e) {
//handle the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) throws IOException {
        try {
            uploadComplete = true;

//does things 

    public boolean isUploadComplete() {
        return uploadComplete;
    }

    public void setUploadComplete(boolean uploadComplete) {
        this.uploadComplete = uploadComplete;
    }
```

In the console i have set it to out print at each time uploadComplete changes from false to true and i get :

```
INFO: Upload complete value before copy file false
INFO: upload complete value is : true
```

As you can see the value changes from false to true, the issue is the button never becomes active again, why is this ?

This works just fine, no errors etc, it is just the button issue

EDIT :

After some testing i have found with this code:

```
<p:commandButton id="Nav" action="#{navigationBean.naviagtion}"   value="Next"  ajax="False" update ="Nav" disabled="#{fileUploadController.uploadComplete}"/>
```

it makes the button live on start up but when i upload the file it and click on the button it refreshes the page and then becomes disables, the exact oposite of what i want to happen lol, so how can this action be reveresed ? i have tried swapping around the true and false statements but this did not work, this never made the button disabled

How can i flip the controls so it does the opposite of what is doing now

Comment: Can you reorganize your code to be at least compilable? Please.

Comment: @OP: you may try to use the "update" attribute to re-render the commandbutton or its parent. Also, please use a Logging facility instead of the Sysouts.

Comment: how would i use the update attrbute as i think it is working now and just not being re-rendered and this is causing it to stay disabled

Comment: update="id_of_the_element" for example, update=":formid:commandbuttonid"

Comment: Thanks, sadly that has not solved my issue of the button being backwards in the way it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [our latest conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923037/how-to-hide-a-button-until-an-action-is-completed-primefaces/14923185#comment20942072_14923185) I had a look at the [official documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html).
I found that, like Sujoy commented, `p:fileOupload` has an attribute `update`, that renders a component after the upload has finished. So you update your `Nav` via adding `update="Nav"` to your `<p:fileUpload>`. This way your button should be re-rendered properly.
Also maybe you should switch `disabled="#{fileUploadController.uploadComplete}"/>` back to `disabled="#{!fileUploadController.uploadComplete}"/>` since if `uploadComplete == true`,  the button should *not* be disabled.
**You have to place update in the upload-component, not in the button itself!**
Hopefully your testing hasn't messed up your code ;)